# The GMP Library Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2017 CE

Tags: boost, windows-7, linker, visual-studio-2017, c++17

I'm trying to use the boost's multi-precision math library. I'm using visual studio 2017 CE with the latest version and compiler setting to latest draft standard. I have the newest version of boost installed and working 1.66. However, one of boost headers includes `gmp.h`. So I went to `GNU's GMP` site and downloaded the library, and extracted it to a folder where I want the library to reside.

I was reading through their documentation on how to install the library, but it is completely lacking in any directions for installing on windows. The only thing it does mention under windows is mingw in which I'm not using. I'm using visual c++.

Is there any way to resolve this in order to use boost's multiprecision headers?

I've been reading up a little bit about the MPFR library; if I install that instead of GMP will that take care of the needed files to successfully compile, link and build the boost's mp library?

Comment: Look at http://mpir.org/ . It is a fork of GMP that includes better Windows support.

Comment: @casevh I currently am. I've been following some procedures and I was able to build libraries for mpir, but I'm struggling to build the libraries for mpfr. I'll have to continue to work at it; for right now I have to leave; I'll come back to it later in the day. Thank you for the response though.